# Why is BMI measured in units of $\text{kg}/\text{m}^2$?

Tags: dimensional-analysis, biology

[Body mass index (BMI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_mass_index) is a convenient rule of thumb used to broadly categorize a person as underweight, normal weight, overweight, or obese. Where $m$ is body mass and $h$ is height, it is defined as:
$$BMI\equiv\frac{m}{h^2}$$
This seems to imply that human body mass scales with height *squared* instead of height cubed. Why is this?

Comment: That sounds like a physiological question, that I don't know the answer to.  BMI has been widely criticized over the years, including for its scalability.  You may be interested in this section of that wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_mass_index#Limitations

Comment: As a former fat kid who loved math I used to always wonder this...but as others have said; not really a physics question

Comment: I would guess it has something to do with scaling the cross sectional are of body size. This probably has to do with the volume/ area problem where an animals bones strength is given by there cross sectional area where as the animals weight depending on volume.

Comment: It is already answered here https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/8118/